# Android Appcompat-v7 Error

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-appcompat

I am using android studio 2.3.1, In android build.gradle

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

has error

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 24.0.0, 23.4.0. Examples include `com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0` and `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0`

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'   

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wsolus.chathuranga.simplifya"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 22
    versionName "2.0.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
} } dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
  compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
    exclude module: "httpclient"
}
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'

}
```

please help me 
Thanks

This is a screen shot of the gradle:

[image: This is a screen shot of the gradle]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your gradle file like this and then go to **file->Invalidate cache and restart**.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'   

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wsolus.chathuranga.simplifya"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 22
    versionName "2.0.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
} } dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
  compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
    exclude module: "httpclient"
}
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.2.0'

}
```

Comment: I do like this then it told buildToolsVersion "24.0.0" is too old and want to update "25.0.0" I do it but problem is same

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
```

First Change your **CompileSDK** and **build tool version** to

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
```

And Change Your dependancy to
Comment your appcompat dependancy and version up to your other dependancy.
I also got this error. this will work for me.

```
   //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

thank you :)